# How to change header height in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

I'm trying to change the header height dynamically within my Javascript code (within the second if statement). Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
var currentDate =  new Date();
    // Months are zero indexed, so for 21 December:
    var saleStart = new Date("12-10-2017");
    var saleEnd = new Date("12-19-2019");

    if (saleStart <= currentDate && currentDate <= saleEnd && sessionStorage.getItem('firstVisit') === null) {
        // Set display to '' (empty string) so the element adopts its default or inherited value
        $(".sale_banner").show();
        $(".hover_bkgr_fricc").show();
        sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisit', '1');

    }
    else if(saleStart <= currentDate && currentDate <= saleEnd)
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName('header').style.height="140px";
        $(".sale_banner").show();
    }
    else{
        $(".sale_banner").hide();

    }
```

For some reason the line to change the header height does nothing! I've also tried using `getElementbyId` but that does nothing too!

My `header.phtml` file opens with the following tag:

```
<header class="desktop">
```

This is the section of CSS I'm trying to change:

```
header.desktop {
  height: 173px;
  background-color: #6E348C;
}
```

I've used `header, desktop, header.desktop` in the parentheses but still no luck! This is the error I get on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (myproject.js:28)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: please add the relevant HTML and/or create a Minimal and reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using getElementsByClassName always returns an array, you might want to change that to

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.height="140px";
```

That assuming you only have one header element, it would be nice if you could use id instead of class names

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have also tried putting a zero array index in but still no luck :( the css I'm trying to change is `header.desktop`, should I still use 'header' in the parentheses?

Comment: Is there a chance that you can use <header> with an id? So you can use document.getElementById('desktopHeader').style.height="140px"

Comment: Your answer did the trick! Adding an id for the header was what was needed! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your HTML code, but I guess you don't have a `header` class.
Your CSS suggests you have a `header` tag with a `desktop` class (header.desktop)
Then, you should try with `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelector`, :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('desktop')
// or
document.querySelector('.desktop')
```

You can use any of them, but `querySelector` is a more modern method and only returns one element (if you have several elements with the same classname, then try `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`)

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

**UPDATE:**
Try this

```js
function changeHeight() {
  // Note that the class name is 'desktop', while 'header' is the name of the HTML tag
  document.querySelector('.desktop').style.height = "100px"
}
```

```css
header.desktop {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #6E348C;
}
```

```html
<header class="desktop">This is the header</header>
<button onclick="changeHeight()">Change height</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried your code but still no luck unfortunately. Would I still use `style.height` in the same way? Like this: `document.querySelector('.desktop').style.height="140px";`. I'll update my post to show my HTML now! :)

Comment: You should paste your HTML

Comment: I've just pasted the HTML snippet. The only relevant part is where I open the header tag.